# defining dict key with If statement

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have this code to print values in columns from a dictionary:

```
Dim dBT As Object 'global dictionary

Sub buttonpresscount()

    'constants for column positions
    Const COL_BLOCK As Long = 1
    Const COL_TRIAL As Long = 2
    Const COL_ACT As Long = 7
    Const COL_AOI As Long = 8
    Const COL_RT As Long = 16

    Dim rng As Range, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Dim d, r As Long, k, resBT()

    Set sht = Worksheets("full test")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dBT = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = sht.Range("B7:Q" & lastrow)

    d = rng.Value  'get the data into an array

    ReDim resBT(1 To UBound(d), 1 To 1) 'resize the array which will
                                        '  be placed in ColT
    'get unique combinations of Block and Trial and pressedcounts for each
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_ACT) <> "", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)         'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("T7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

    'clear dictionary
    dBT.RemoveAll

'count AOI entries
 For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If d(r, 20) = 1 Then
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("U7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT
```

When defining the key for counting AOI entries, I only want keys for trials that have a value of 1 in column T. So I've inserted an If statement here:

```
'count AOI entries
 For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If d(r, 20) = 1 Then
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r
```

But I don't think I've defined the cell address properly, as I get a "subscript out of range" error on the "If" line.

I've tried defining Col T as a constant like COL_AOI or COL_RT but it also doesn't work. I don't know what else the problem could be.

Comment: Can you include the part of your code where you declare the variable `d`, and the part where you assign a value to it.  Maybe also place a `Debug.Print UBound(d, 2)` immediately before the `If` statement and tell us what it says.

Comment: There you go @YowE3K

Comment: Of course! That works, Thank you. Still want to see what Debug.Print UBound(d, 2) says?

Comment: No - once I saw the line setting the variable I knew what the size of the second dimension would be.  (16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that column T is not accessible in your array is that you are creating the array by saying:

```
Set rng = sht.Range("B7:Q" & lastrow)
d = rng.Value
```

This will only copy in the values between columns B and Q.  In order to access column T as well, change that statement to be:

```
Set rng = sht.Range("B7:T" & lastrow)
d = rng.Value
```

(or, more simply, just use `d = sht.Range("B7:T" & lastrow).Value`)

You should then be able to access values from column T by using statements such as:

```
If d(r, 19) = 1 Then
```

(Use 19, not 20, because column B will be in position `r, 1` of the array, column C will be in position `r, 2` of the array, etc.)

Comment: So this solution worked the first time, and then I cleared the results and tried again, and it is not printing anything in Col U.

Comment: @shecodes Your code says to reset the count for a key if column T has anything other than a 1 in it.  So, do you have any cases where the last entry for a key contains a 1 in column T?

Comment: most of the keys should have a value of 1 in column T. some of them will have 2, possibly higher. Not sure what you mean by the last entry. WOuld you like to see the data file for clarification?  [It's here](http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest_1).

Comment: (a) I refuse to access 3rd party (possibly virus-infected) sites, so please include any data that is needed to resolve the problem into the question.  That also helps future users of the site, because the 3rd party site may have changed its pages by the time they look at the question.  (b) Are you trying to test based on the original values of column T, or on the revised values of column T (i.e. the values you store in `resBT`)?

Comment: I only want values to be assigned to keys and printed based on the original values in Col T. before Col T is filled with the values from the dict, the cells in Col T are all empty.

Comment: @shecodes - if the values in column T are all empty, none of them will be equal to 1, therefore your `If d(r, 19) = 1 Then` statement will fall into the `Else` code, which says to set `dbt(k)` to an empty string.  `dbt(k)` is then used to populate `resBT` which is then written to column U.  So ... column T empty --> column U empty.

Comment: I was under the impression that putting the if statement where it is would look at the values after they had been changed to 1's. How do I change it so that this is the case? Change d(r, 19) to resBT(r, 19)?

Comment: @shecodes - change `d(r, 19)` to `resBT(r, 1)` (the second dimension of `resBT` is always 1 in your code - it's only one "column" wide).  `d` still contains only the values read in at the start of your code, and hasn't been changed while your code is processing.